# Posting entire array (without duplicates) to mongolab with Javascript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, for-loop, xmlhttprequest, mlab

In my code I have a for loop which iterates the objects in an array (this is obviously not the problem). Further, I manage to post this array to the database:

```
var jsonObject = '{"object":' + '"' + array + '"' + '}';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", MYAPIURL);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(jsonObject);
```

The problem is that I need to check the DB if some of the objects within the array already exists! Therefor I thought making a new for-loop and open a new XMLHttpRequest for each of the objects withing the array would help me, but I can't get it to work. With the code below it just posts the last object within the array as many times as there are objects in the array.

Code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < objectList.length; i++){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", MYAPIURL);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

        var response = xhr.responseText;

        if(response.length === 0){                     
            var jsonObject = '{"collectedobject":' + '{"objectname" : "' + objectList[i] + '", "weight" : 1}}';

            xhr.open("POST", MYAPIURL);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.send(jsonObject);

        } else {
            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                var tempObject = response[i];
                var newWeight = tempObject.collectedobject.weight + 1;
                var updatedJson = '{"collectedobject":{"objectname" : "' + tempObject.collectedobject.objectname + '", "weight" : ' + newWeight + '}}';

                xhr.open("PUT", MYAPIURL );              
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                xhr.send(updatedJson);
            }
        }
    }            
    xhr.send();
}
```

I've sort of come up with a solution, but it is as bad as it can get!

```
for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", MYAPI);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if(response.length === 0){   
        for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){                  
            var jsonObject = '{"spider":' + '{"url" : "' + urls[i] + '", "weight" : 1}}';
            alert("PostToDB: " + jsonObject);
            xhr.open("POST", "MYAPI");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.send(jsonObject);
        }
    }
...
```

What I've done is to add a loop before opening a connection to the API/DB, then I iterate the array containing the urls before working further with them. The problem is that this does not work without the alert. The alert seems to set a timeout or something. If I remove the alert the only object being posted to DB is the last one in the array (and yes, I've tried with several arrays!)

Anyone got any ideas to my "new" problem?

Comment: Have you checked this one? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Comment: Uhm, actually I haven't. Thanks for that, but it doesn't seem to fit me entirely. As you see from the code withing the "else" I also need the "weight" element to increment by one each time we find similar elements.